# FATAL EXCEPTION: main при попытке прочитать Extras Intent'а

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle, android-parcelable

Имеется фрагмент со списком объектов. При нажатии на элемент списка формируется `Intent` и запускается `startActivityForResult`

```
Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick position: " + position);
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MealDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ID_KEY, position);  //позиция в списке
intent.putExtra(MEALNAME,mMeals.get(position));  //Parcelable объект 
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(intent));
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra(ID_KEY,0)));
Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(intent.getExtras()));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EDIT_TYPE);
```

В дебаг при этом пишется

```
onItemClick position: 1
Intent { cmp=com.seysen.hikingmealsforandroid/.MealDetailActivity (has extras) }
1
Bundle[{meal=Porridge, meal_id=1}]
```

Вроде бы сформировано все верно. Запускаемое Activity при создании в `onCreate` инициализирует шаблон и проверяет, а были ли ему переданы `Extras`

```
Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (arguments!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Has arguments " + String.valueOf(arguments));
        position = arguments.getInt(ID_KEY);
        Log.d(TAG,"Position = " + position);
    }
```

И дальше можно не продолжать, потому-что приложение вылетает.
В дебаге при этом:

```
Meal Detail Created
Has arguments Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=648]
```

В логе при этом `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` и еще интересная информация `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@acfe48b8: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 156` и ссылка на строку

```
position = arguments.getInt(ID_KEY);
```

При этом в приложении в другом фрагменте список с объектами другого класса с аналогичной реализацией передачи объекта в Activity работает отлично. Единственное отличие, что в работает это с более простым классом `Parcelable` объектов. А в случае, где не работает объекты класса содержат в себе другие объекты класса, реализующего интерфейс `Parcelable`

Comment: А вы уверенны что вы отправляете и извлекаете одинаковый тип данных? Извлекаете `int`, а отправляете `position` который `int` или `long`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev конечно `int`. Даже если я закомментирую эти строчки при попутке извлечь `Parcelable` объект всё равно выпадает эта ошибка

Comment: Скорее всего в вашем Parcelable объекте либо неправильно записывается/читается одно из полей либо он имеет вложенные Parcelable объекты, кде может происходить тоже самое. Проверьте все ли поля вы указали при создании Parcelable объектов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parcelable` объект содержал вложенные `Parcelable` объекты.
В методе `writeToParcel` для вложенных `Parcelable` объектов используется метод `writeTypedList`. Тогда как в конструкторе, используемом в `createFromParcel`, я использовал `readTypedList`, а надо было `createTypedArrayList`.